# MIPS Exception 5 [Addres error in store] occurred

Tags: arrays, assembly, multidimensional-array, mips

So basically I want to implement a 2D Array in MIPS.

I want to have 2 inputs, 1 for columns and 1 for rows.

Then, I want to iterate over the matrix and fill it with numbers.

This is my main function:

```
main:

li $v0,5    # Storing column number
syscall

move $s0,$v0    

li $v0,5    # Storing row number
syscall

move $s1,$v0

la $a0,array
move $a1,$s0
move $a2,$s1
jal loadArray  # Jumping to function for filling the matrix
```

My main function calls a function in my *.text* segment

```
loadArray:
    move $t0,$a0#copying address
    li $t1,0    #t1 row counter
    li $t2,0    #t2 column counter

columnLoop:
    beq $t1,$a1,rowLoop 

# formula for going through matrix
    mul $t3,$a1,$a2 
    mul $t3,$t3,$t2
    mul $t4,$t1,4
    add $t3,$t3,$t4
    add $t3,$t3,$t0

    addi $t1,$t1,1 #rowcounter++ 

    li $v0,5
    syscall

    sw $v0,($t3)#storing a int
    j kolonaLoop

rowLoop:
    beq $t2,$a2,end
    li $t1,0    #rowcounter=0
    add $t2,$t2,1    # columncouter++
    j columnLoop     # loop into row loop
end:
    jr $ra
```

I'm going through the matrix with a formula

```
addr=baseaddres+(_currColumn_ * _number of Rows_ * _nuOfRows_) + (_currRow_*4)
```

And time after time, I get an error:

> Exception 5 [Address error in store]

I troubleshot, tried to align the address in my *.data* segment

```
.data
.align 2 #I even aligned the address 
blanko: .asciiz " "
Array: .space 300
```

Been at this for hours, please help

Comment: You are aligning your `blanko` instead of your `Array`. Also you want to align to 4 not 2 (although in your assembler `.align 2` might mean 2^2). Use your debugger/simulator to examine the faulting instruction and the register values at that point.

Comment: Tried that, still getting the error

Comment: You don't actually need any multiplies inside the inner loop, just increment a pointer by 4 bytes.  (And multiply by 4 should always be a shift, not a mul).  Anyway, use a debugger to see what address you actually have in a register and add that to the question (or just use it yourself to debug).